# MongoDB field name in Lift's Record Field

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

I have a pre-existing database, and this code:

```
class User private() extends MongoRecord[User] with StringPk[User] {
  def meta = User

  object createdAt extends DateTimeField(this)
  object lastLogin extends DateTimeField(this)

  object password extends StringField(this, 128)
      object salt extends StringField(this, 128)
}

object User extends User with MongoMetaRecord[User]
```

The problem is, in my database, the field `createdAt` is called `created-at`, and similar with `lastLogin`. Looking into the [docs](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.record.field.DateTimeField), there are several object fields that could be doing the job (`label`, `name`, `title`, `uniqueFieldId`), so which one would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The member `name` seems to be the one looking for. As in

```
object createdAt extends DateTimeField(this) {
  def name = "created-at"
}
```